# how do update a model after the return statement

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a view when should update the model data as "Sent" after rendering to template. I want to exclude things that are already sent then update the value no (number) as sent then return the data to the template.

the problem is that if i use it as it is it seem to do all three liunes in one go and excludes the no as its been sent,, how can I update it as sent AFTER the data is returned.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        lab = request.GET.get('lab', None)

        audit = models.SendAudit.objects.filter(no__exact=labno).exclude(status__contains='sent')

        models.SendAudit.objects.select_related().filter(no__exact=labno).update(status='{Sent}')

        return render(request, self.template_name2, {'audit': audit, 'no': no})
```

Comment: `QuerySet`s are lazy, so that means that as long as you do not *iterate* over the query, or call `len(..)` or *consume* the queryset in another way, it will not *run* the query.

Comment: thanks - what would you recommend over QuerySet ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QuerySet`s are lazy, so that means that as long as you do not *iterate* over the query, or call `len(…)` or *consume* the queryset in another way, it will not *run* the query.

You can use `list(…)` to materialize the `QuerySet` into a list for example:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    lab = request.GET.get('lab')
    qs = models.SendAudit.objects.filter(no=labno)
    audit = list(qs.exclude(status__contains='sent'))
    qs.update(status='{Sent}')
    return render(request, self.template_name2, {'audit': audit, 'no': no})
```

It howeever does not make much sense to make updates in a GET request. A GET request is *not* supposed to have side-effects by the HTTP standard. A POST/PATCH/PUT/… request can have side-effects.

Comment: the get request is needed to do other aspects of the function which are not integral to the final render. thank you this works,